# Using iOS Safari Reader to email myself the meat of the web page I am viewing

Tags: feature-request

On many sites, Safari's reader is a great way to email myself the meat of the web page I am viewing, with no distracting adds and includes all pages of the article itself, as in it follows all the hyperlinks to next pages. Unfortunately, on StackOverflow the rendering stops at first post.

I like the layout of StackOverflow, but I'd really like to be able to email myself the entire page, not just the question posted.

Comment: OK, I have a question.  We're having this nice discussion [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/how-to-save-the-world-one-question-title-at-a-time) about question titles, and I'd just like to know... Why did you put "Using iOS Safari Reader" in the title of your question, rather than the actual question you had?

Comment: Hmm ... I will take confusion as my defense ... I thought the titles were supposed to be short and concise. I was not trying anything sneaky like you've implied. And, I was submitting a feature request, not a question. Sincerely, Ignoramous.

Comment: No implication was intended.  We're just genuinely trying to figure out why people put the things in titles that they do.

Answer (score 1):

I think Safari uses some variant of [Readability](http://www.readability.com/) to do that. If you try that tool itself, it might behave different than Safari and it might be able to handle StackOverflow correctly now.

Comment: Same behavior, articles are cut off before the first answer.