# What to do with questions with general title but specific content?

Tags: discussion, questions

Every now and then I am looking for some general solution, find an apt question title, then cannot help but feel a little bit put off because the question actually asks for something far more specific. This may lead to answers that are actually unsuitable for the general problem.

The latest example I came upon is the question [Two-dimensional ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693997/multi-dimensional-arraylist) which *appears* to be about multidimensional `ArrayList`s in Java, but the question body is about only a 2-dimensional `ArrayList`.

Another example is this question which asks for a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) in the title but talks about a 'pair' in the body: [Using Pairs or 2-tuples in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-tuples-in-java)

---

**edit**: after JeroenVannevel's comment, edited both questions to reflect their more narrow nature. So the resolved and replaced titles cannot demonstrate their original stance here anymore.

---

If you add that some of us *stackoverflowers* (just like other people) sometimes tend to attempt to give non-direct answers (not to speak of non-direct questions like the ones mentioned), you have a problem: the solution to the more general title quickly evaporates from the conversation.

For example, in the first question linked, the answers propose a `Map`, and in the second one linked, they uninterestingly propose some kind of a `Pair<X,Y>`. They leave the title's general question untouched. Then the title occupies the general-sounding entry in the search's listing.

Now what if one is interested in the actual general problem? If the question is asked again with a similar title, it will got confusing to quickly see which question is which, from the listing.

The other possibility, I am not sure, isn't it rude to edit the older question in order to make room for the actual general question?

How to make room for the actual general question?

Comment: Edit the title so it reflects the content, nothing rude about it at all.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel well, ok then! :)

Comment: Here is an interesting [thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/how-to-save-the-world-one-question-title-at-a-time) related to this subject.