# Answer what is asked, not what is intended

Tags: discussion

How many times have you googled a question to find a similar one that's been asked, but the asker was actually ignorant of their problem, and thanks to comment prodding and editing of the question post, the content is now completely irrelevant or at best tangential to the question title itself?

I've noticed this quite a bit, and I believe there's good reason for it.  This style of answering gets answers accepted and ratings bumped.  For the asker and the answerer, this is all fine and well, but what about the 10's, or 100's, or even 1000's of people down the line who will type that same question into google, only to find 5 similar questions, and just 1 of which explicitly answers the title question?  That's a lot of wasted time for people, as well as wasted cpu cycles and server memory.

What I propose is a simple guideline for answering questions:  **You just answer the question.**

You don't try to figure out what their real problem is.  You don't try to decipher what the asker means.  You simply answer what's there and nothing more.

What I think will likely improve:

- *Less question overlap* - When a question gets answered at face value, it will be revealed for all others who view it at a later time whether or not it's applicable to their problem, thus leading them to ask different questions.
- *Better questions* - This guideline will pressure the asker to make more precise questions, and do some pre-evaluation of their problem before asking so as not to waste people's time for an answer that doesn't fix things.
- *Answering questions will be easier and faster* - Less time will be spent by answerers trying to read between the lines, or fish for information about the problem that has nothing to do with the question title.
- *Less time wasted for future askers* - I think this is the true value of these guidelines.  Many people will save a lot of time from this in the long run, especially the longer a guideline like this is enforced and polluted questions become more scarce.

What I think will be more difficult:

- *More newbie frustration* - Getting a face-value answer to a question will be frustrating to some for sure, but I believe in the long run this will train them to ask better questions.
- *Resistance to adoption* - Let's face it, getting points for answering questions is nice.  But if that means going against some suggested guidelines to get it, what would you do?
- *Accepting answers* - This is tricky because a person can get an answer to a question, but have it not solve their problem, and then how would the asker know it's right to accept it?  I'm not sure what the solution would be for this.

In conclusion I think some sort of guidelines like this would be more beneficial for all people (present AND future) than the current system.  I think it's at least worthy of consideration though I understand implementation on a scale of a site as big as SO would be challenging.

Comment: "You don't try to figure out what their real problem is" in short no no and no. I would consider this the antitheses of actually helping some one

Comment: Related well-established FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133299

Comment: I don't see the need for the knee-jerk reaction to down vote.  I thought it might spark up an interesting conversation of the merits of each approach to answering.  I'm not trying to start a revolution, relax.

Comment: If you really wanted to start a conversation, you should have phrased the question neutrally and asked which style is preferred... instead you told a large group of people that the way they've been doing things is bad and ineffective. You're not asking what people think, you're telling them to change... which rarely goes over well. Regardless, voting on Meta is different. Downvotes mean they disagree with you, they do not mean that the question is bad.

Comment: @Dragon:  All I'm trying to point out is the problems this causes for the (potentially thousands) of people googling a similar question in the future.  This system would be helping them quite a bit.

Comment: @Catija: Fair enough and point taken.

Comment: Related: [How to save the world...one question title at a time?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201940) and [General reference questions create low quality dead ends for googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160565)

Comment: What about the poor OP who originally asked the question seeking help? should you ignore him in favor of potential future readers?

Comment: @Dagon Not if he is prepared to work with you to quickly improve his question, but otherwise, yes.  The paragraph headed **You gotta get this to get us.** at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here describes the SE model well.

Comment: "Every time I drink poison, I get deathly sick.  But I need to drink poison so I can get my college degree.  How can I drink poison without getting sick?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the approach you suggest may be missing the point that editing tools are provided to everyone to keep improving every question (including its title and tags) and its answer(s).

If you see a Q&A where:

> the content is now completely irrelevant or at best tangential to the
>   question title itself

then edit its title, body, tags and/or answers to restore/improve its relevance.

If its content seems irretrievable then consider flagging or voting for its closure.

Any answer that does not answer the question should be edited, commented upon and/or downvoted to ensure that it does - or be deleted.

Personally, I usually try to just answer the question as my starting point, but if I can see a useful question is being masked by poor question content, I will try to work with the asker to improve their question (by commenting, editing, perhaps downvoting, etc) before I answer it.

Comment: I didn't realize that was an encouraged practice, but I agree that does seem to offer a solution to the problem.

Comment: Of course, virtually nobody ever does any of these things, so the site just ends up being left with millions of bad questions with answers that won't help anyone but the OP.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't try to figure out what their real problem is. You don't try
>   to decipher what the asker means. You simply answer what's there and
>   nothing more.

That then would mean that a majority of our questions would be either unanswerable, or the answers would be useless to both the asker and many future viewers.

> Less question overlap - When a question gets answered at face value,
>   it will be revealed for all others who view it at a later time whether
>   or not it's applicable to their problem, thus leading them to ask
>   different questions.

Do you really believe that this will be the case? Have you *seen* some of the stuff that gets asked on StackOverflow? Its an exercise in divination and guiding the user to clarify, without which the questions are either unanswerable or trivial and useless.

> Answering questions will be easier and faster - Less time will be
>   spent by answerers trying to read between the lines, or fish for
>   information about the problem that has nothing to do with the question
>   title.

The goal here isn't to churn as many answers as soon as possible, it is to provide **QUALITY** QA

> Better questions - This guideline will pressure the asker to make more
>   precise questions, and do some pre-evaluation of their problem before
>   asking so as not to waste people's time for an answer that doesn't fix
>   things.

We have that quality control now, its called vote to close and downvote.

> I think it's at least worthy of consideration though I understand
>   implementation on a scale of a site as big as SO would be challenging.

I think that would be tens of thousands of hours of volunteers down the drain either closing all of the new bad questions instead of fixing them where its possible, and further thousands of hours of volunteers down the drain answering trivial or useless questions.

Comment: You're basically just asserting that people should be answering bad questions, instead of trying to fix them, because there are so many bad questions.  SO's premise from the start is to be a place to find quality answers to *quality* questions, not a place to find something resembling an answer to something resembling a question.

Comment: @Servy you do realise I am arguing _against_ OPs proposal, right?

Comment: Yes, I do realize that.